# Processing credit cards with delayed job securely

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

Currently I'm processing credit card payments through a payment gateway. My apps uses Rails, hosted on heroku with unicorn.

The unicorn process will timeout after 30 seconds however, so if a gateway transaction hasn't finished in time for whatever reason the request fails leaving the user with an App error and a partially completed transaction.

To overcome this I'd like to use DelayedJob, which I'm already using to handle the transaction as a background process.

One issue that comes to mind however, is that delayed job stores jobs in a table and therefore the credit card info would be temporarily stored unencrypted.

How can I overcome this issue? Or is there a better solution using delayed job?

Could I encrypt the credit card details first before using delayed job and then have delayed job encrypt before processing - although I'm not sure this would be PCI compliant?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could send the request to your processor in a new thread then store the result when they return. This allows the request to finish quickly regardless of your processor's behavior. The page that initiated the thread could then simply say "processing" and force a page reload or check via ajax periodically until the processor returns and the result is stored.

In this setup you are not storing the credit card information in your database or worrying about encrypting / decrypting data. See https://www.agileplannerapp.com/blog/building-agile-planner/rails-background-jobs-in-threads for more information on processing in background threads on Heroku.

Comment: Interesting. So does the new Thread actually run in a heroku worker or web dyno?

Comment: This would be run on the Heroku web dyno. When you call Thread.new with a block it splits off and starts performing that logic in a separate thread. The original thread keeps processing the request at this point as it is not blocked by your new thread's actions.

At the link provided they show how to use this method to send emails from your web dyno on Heroku. You could simply refactor their example to call the payment processor. Pay attention to the ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close call that is made before the end of the thread.

Comment: If it's simply starting a new thread in a web dyno, would this new thread not also be limited to a 30 second timeout from unicorn. It would make the users experience nicer but not solve the sometimes long payment gateway processing times.

Comment: The new thread doesn't have to worry about the timeout. The request to your application has a 30 second timeout (see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout). With this setup your request should return quickly while the thread (spawned by the request) runs until it is complete.

Comment: That being said the dyno will automatically be put to sleep after 1 hour of inactivity. See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos

Answer (score 0):

Some payment gateways, such as Braintree, provide a transparent redirect capability to alleviate PCI compliance concerns.  When using a transparent redirect, the credit card information is submitted directly to the payment gateway, and the payment gateway returns a payment token that can be used by your application to authorize and make charges against that credit card.

In this setup, the customer credit card data never even passes through your rails server, which means you don't need to be concerned over possible storage of the credit card info form parameters in your web server or application log files.

If you were to switch to using a transparent redirect with your payment gateway, you could then store the returned payment token in your delayed job information and have greatly reduced PCI compliance concerns.

Comment: The transparent redirect feature sounds really good. Unfortunately I'm not in a position to change payment gateways. You did answer one of my questions